# How to set prorate_behavior when checkout is handled by stripe's customers portal

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a product that handles the checkout session entirely from stripe's customer portal (we don't use stripe's API); we then hear the webhooks to handle our inner logic. I want to set the `prorate_behavior` to `always_invoice`, so that way customers are charged for the prorated price.

I have the customers portal configured like this:

[image]

But it's not working because when a user upgrades, we still see the proration as false in the logs of the event:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this? I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I know what's going on here but can you clarify what object you are looking at that is showing the `proration: false` property?  What is the event type you are looking at in the logs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RyanM, it's the invoice.paid event log

Comment: Did you figure this out? Trying it myself now and noticing that when I modify the subscription after customer.updated webhook, it still doesn't reflect it in the UI.